# Wait until my BackgroundWorker finish in order to open new BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application i am checking my files by open Wireshark process before add to my Listbox.
this is Add Directory click event who take root folder and checking all this files inside this folder and sub folders:

```
private void btnAddDir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ThreadStart threadStart = delegate
            {
                foreach (string file in SafeFileEnumerator.EnumerateFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref numWorkers);
                    StartBackgroundFileChecker(file);
                }
            };

            Thread thread = new Thread(threadStart);
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { }
}

private void StartBackgroundFileChecker(string file)
{
    ListboxFile listboxFile = new ListboxFile();
    listboxFile.OnFileAddEvent += listboxFile_OnFileAddEvent;
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker.DoWork +=
    (s3, e3) =>
    {
        //check my file
    };

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref numWorkers) == 0)
    {
        //update my UI
    }
}
```

When i am checking this file i am open `Wireshark` process so if i choose folder with many files, many `Wireshark` processes opned and this take a lot on memory, 
how can i wait until my BackgroundWorker finish and only then open new one ?

Comment: Pretty sure I already commented on this code.  Exact same advice, move the foreach loop inside the worker so you only ever need one BGW.  Waiting for threads is always a bad idea, your code will deadlock.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I understand you want only single background worker launched at time. If so, then try this (based on [System.Threading.AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx))

```
//introduce additional field
private AutoResetEvent _workerCompleted = new AutoResetEvent(false);
//modify StartBackgroundFileChecker
private void StartBackgroundFileChecker(string file)
{
    ListboxFile listboxFile = new ListboxFile();
    listboxFile.OnFileAddEvent += listboxFile_OnFileAddEvent;
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker.DoWork +=
    (s3, e3) =>
    {
        //check my file
    };

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
   //new code - wait for completion
   _workerCompleted.WaitOne();
}
//add completion notification to backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted
void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref numWorkers) == 0)
    {
        //update my UI
    }

    //new code - notify about completion
    _workerCompleted.Set();
}
```

In that solution your background thread will start new BackgroundWorker one by one - this can be not optimal (you could avoid BackgroundWorker at all and simply update UI via Dispatch in *threadStart* delegate)

In my opinion better to control number of parallel threads and still process files in multiple but limited numbers of threads.

Here is the alternative solution (based on System.Threading.Tasks namespace):

```
 private void btnAddDir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   var selectedPath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
           
            var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(selectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            Parallel.ForEach(files,
                             new ParallelOptions
                             {
                                     MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 // limit number of parallel threads here 
                             },
                             file =>
                             {
                                 //process file here - launch your process
                             });
        }).ContinueWith(
            t => { /* when all files processed. Update your UI here */ }
            ,TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() // to ContinueWith (update UI) from UI thread
        );
}
```

You can tweak  this solution for your specific needs.

Used classes/methods (see MSDN for reference):

- [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)
- TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext
- Parallel.ForEach Method (IEnumerable, ParallelOptions, Action)

Comment: I think control number of parallel will be much better

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this, instead of the foreach keep a List of the files and after complete just take the first element and update your List

```
private List<string> _files;

private void btnAddDir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            _files = new List<string>(SafeFileEnumerator.EnumerateFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));

            Interlocked.Increment(ref numWorkers);
            var file = _files.FirstOrDefault();
            if(file != null)
                StartBackgroundFileChecker(file);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { }
}

private void StartBackgroundFileChecker(string file)
{
    ListboxFile listboxFile = new ListboxFile();
    listboxFile.OnFileAddEvent += listboxFile_OnFileAddEvent;
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker.DoWork +=
    (s3, e3) =>
    {
        //check my file
    };

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref numWorkers) == 0)
    {
        //update my UI
        _files = _files.Skip(1);
        var file = _files.FirstOrDefault();
        if(file != null)
            StartBackgroundFileChecker(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that i am using EnumerateFiles in order to get all the files "in process", i don't want to wait until i get all the files

Comment: You can convert it to a List of string, and you will get all the files in proccess, but each files will be processed after the Backgroundworker finished. Where does the backgroundworker open wireshark?

Comment: The wireshark open the process via another class where wrote //check my file